# Should not converting an answer to a comment keep the votes its comments have?

Tags: support, convert-to-comment

I have converted an answer to a comment for an existing answer, as that answer was really a comment for the answer, rather than an answer.
When doing that, I noticed the votes on the existing comment were cleared.

[image: screenshot]

Should not the existing votes for the comments be maintained?
As the comments are still present, it is useful for the future readers to know how users perceived the given comments, especially when there are more than one comment, and some of those comments are voted from at least two users.
In this case, removing the comment for the answer doesn't make sense, as the comment is saying that what reported by the other user is true in a specific case, and not always.

Comment: I've always thought this should be the case, even though it may seem trivial to some. More so, I think the deleted answer should convert it's vote total to comment votes.